# Eclipse Luna , Project Wizard giving option to create XML Schema file .xsd but not XSL file?

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt, eclipse-plugin

When I Follow these steps
New -> 
Others->
Select a wizard
  XML
      DTD File
      XML File
      XML Schema File
  Examples

As you can see there is no option to add a xsl file ?
Do I need to install any kind of plugin. WTP version 3.6  is  present already

Comment: What is "WTP version 3.6 is present already" supposed to mean? Are you sure you have the XSL Tools installed?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem , just needed to install a Web Tool Platform(WTP) Plugin for eclipse Luna .
Then I got the required options.